# Which Mac OS X versions support lsof command?

Tags: macos, mac, leopard, versions

I want to know which Mac OS X versions support the `lsof` command. Does Mac OS X 10.5 support it?

Comment: Support, or ship with?  (They may, of course, be one and the same.)

Answer (score 3):

`lsof` has been available since OS X 10.5. From the manual page :

```
   Lsof  revision 4.87 lists on its standard output file information about
   files opened by processes for the following UNIX dialects:

        Apple Darwin 9 and Mac OS X 10.[567]
```